Centroid of $\Omega$ and $\partial\Omega$ concides then $\Omega$ must be a ball
Hi I just happened to have a small question. If we have
$$\frac{\int_\Omega x}{|\Omega|}=\frac{\int_{\partial\Omega} x}{|\partial\Omega|}$$
for a simply connected set $\Omega$ with analytic boundary. Does this mean that $\Omega$ is a ball?
I believe this problem was proven. But I cannot find the reference.

Edit: I realised that there are many counterexamples. One of which is given in the answer by Gerard. Thanks for your help.

Won't this hold for any set with (nice boundary and) a point symmetry?

Yes you are right. Sorry for asking an easy question.

As Sean said, it can be as smooth as you like.

Depicted ... $\Big\{\big((3+\sin(8t))\cos(t),(3+\sin(8t))\sin(t)\big) : 0 \le t \le 2\pi\Big\}$
